# How to query nested array of jsonb

Tags: json, postgresql

I am working on a PostgreSQL 11 table with a column of nested and multiple jsonb objects

to simulate the issue: -

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
  testcol jsonb
)
insert into test (testcol) values 
('[{"type": {"value": 1, "displayName": "flag1"}, "value": "10"},
{"type": {"value": 2, "displayName": "flag2"}, "value": "20"}, 
{"type": {"value": 3, "displayName": "flag3"}, "value": "30"},
 {"type": {"value": 4, "displayName": "flag4"}},
 {"type": {"value": 4, "displayName": "flag4"}},
 {"type": {"value": 6, "displayName": "flag6"}, "value": "40"}]');
```

I am trying to:

1. get outer value if type= specific value. e.g. get the value 30, if flag3 is in displayname.
2. count occurrence of flag4 in inner json

Comment: because there are two "value" elements, it is not quite clear to me what you are expecting. please add the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `json_to_recordset` to parse it:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  test.id, sub."type"->'value' AS t_value, sub."type"->'displayName' AS t_name, value
  FROM test
  ,LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(testcol) sub("type" jsonb, "value" int)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
-- WHERE ...
-- GROUP BY ...;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f5d21a2478398d9eb48b62536fa4c12f)**

Comment: hi, i tried with command - 'WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  test.id, sub."type"->'value' AS t_value, sub."type"->'displayName' AS t_name, value
  FROM test
  ,LATERAL json_to_recordset(testcol::json) sub("type" jsonb, "value" text)
)
SELECT t_name, value
FROM cte
where t_name::text='flag3';'  but it didnt manage to get flag3, which part i did wrong?

Comment: Don't cast to `json`, use `jsonb_to_recordset` straight away

Comment: @desmond https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4617d873628caff5dc35e64079f5fff2

Comment: it works thanks. but another question, because i have to work with a lot of rows (a row with a jsonb column with 1 to many objects), will this method cause performance issue?

Comment: @desmond It depends on too many things. Normally we should treat data in columns as atomic. If this solution starts perfroming badly you could index/normalize data.